# Div resize with forcing to keep aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take div and resize it according container which is resized on `window.resize` but i need it to mach some specific aspect ratio.

```
var hconainer,wcontainer;
hconainer=$('#container').height();
wconainer=$('#container').width();
now i need that h:w=some specific aspect ratio.
```

Comment: what is the width or height you are resizing it against?

Comment: you have to divide width and height to get ratio. `var ratio = h / w;` and then use that value to resize container to be same proportions.